# Django Queryset two problems

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-queryset

my queryset :

```
Status.objects.filter(date__gte='2017-07-05', date__lt='2017-07-09', type='X').update(value=F('value') + 1)
```

my database :

```
date       | value | value1 | value2 | type  
2017-07-05 |   0   |    0   |    0   |  X
2017-07-06 |   0   |    0   |    0   |  X
2017-07-07 |   0   |    0   |    0   |  X
2017-07-08 |   0   |    0   |    0   |  X
2017-07-09 |   0   |    0   |    0   |  X
2017-07-10 |   0   |    0   |    0   |  X
```

I have two question, but my above queryset don't work.

1 - How update field "value" in date range ?

2 - How to replace "value" with a variable ?

> update(value=F('value') + 1)

I need to dynamically select field (value1, value2, valuse3) from the database to change value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can path a field name with a variable using this.

```
somename='some_field'  #value.value1,... in your case 
Status.objects.filter(Q(date__gte='2017-07-05'), Q(date__lt='2017-07-09'), Q(type='X')).update(**{somename: F(somename)+1})
```